# Detect overflow when overflow set to hidden

Tags: javascript

I have an interesting problem.

Background: I have a simple header. A logo and two links are floated on the left side, while two drop down menu links are floated on the right, all contained in a header div that i 100% width. If I shrink the screen horizontally enough the two drop down menu links dropped below the left-floated elements (of course). After doing some research I decided to use overflow: hidden on the parent header div so that the two drop-down menus would disappear instead of dropping to the next line. This solution works great in my situation. However, I found that the drop-down menu layer was cut off below the header because of the overflow:hidden solution. Just for reference, my drop down menu was created using simple javascript that toggles between css classes to get the drop down effect. I simply added a line to the function onclick events in the javascript that when a menu link is clicked on, overflow changes from overflow:hidden to overflow: none (and of course toggles back to hidden when the menu is unclicked), which works great because there is supposed to never be overflow if the menu buttons are visible (they disappear and are hidden when there is overflow,).

Problem: If a user opens a menu (aka clicks on a drop down menu link) and THEN shrinks the horizontal scrollbar without first closing the menu, the header has an overflow that is still set to none because the user hasn't toggled the header back to hidden because the menu is still open. Thus, my original problem of the two menu links dropping beneath the floated left divs again. Working with what I'm already doing, I'm trying to come up with some kind of onchange() event in the header that will detect when there is overflow, even though overflow is set to hidden. Any thoughts?

Relevant CSS Code:

```
.level1raise { //header class
background: #F8F8F8;
margin: 0px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #BCD2EE;
height: 55px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.level1drop { //alternate header class
background: #F8F8F8;
margin: 0px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #BCD2EE;
height: 55px;
overflow: none;
}
```

Sample of Javascript that toggles menu:

```
function supportdrop() {

if (document.getElementById("support").className == "hidesupportmenu") {
document.getElementById("support").className = "showsupportmenu";
document.getElementById("supportdrop").className = "supportmenuheadclicked";
document.getElementById("supportarrow").className = "uparrowimage";
document.getElementById("help").className = "hidehelpmenu";
document.getElementById("helpdrop").className = "helpmenuhead";
document.getElementById("helparrow").className = "downarrowimage"; //^THESE DEAL WITH MENU
document.getElementById("level1").className = "level1drop"; //THIS IS THE HEADER TOGGLE
} else if (document.getElementById("support").className == "showsupportmenu") {
document.getElementById("support").className = "hidesupportmenu";
document.getElementById("supportdrop").className = "supportmenuhead";
document.getElementById("supportarrow").className = "downarrowimage"; //^MENU
document.getElementById("level1").className = "level1raise"; //HEADER TOGGLE
}

}
```

If you need me to post more code I will, but I think what I've included kind of shows what I'm doing, let me know otherwise. I'd post an attempted solution, but I'm not really sure what solution to attempt. I'm trying to avoid JQuery. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution for any others who are attempting a similar path. Because (1) I use 100% width of the page and the page is dynamic I can disable the horizontal scrollbar and (2) the width of the elements inside the header don't change so I can add up the minimum-required width before the drop down menu links drop to the next line, I can use the following solution:

HTML:

```
<body onresize="checkwidth()">
```

Javascript:

```
function checkwidth() {

var currentwidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth ||  
document.body.clientWidth;

if (currentwidth < 770) {

 document.getElementById("level1").className = "level1raise";
document.getElementById("help").className = "hidehelpmenu";
document.getElementById("helpdrop").className = "helpmenuhead";
document.getElementById("helparrow").className = "downarrowimage";
 document.getElementById("support").className = "hidesupportmenu";
document.getElementById("supportdrop").className = "supportmenuhead";
 document.getElementById("supportarrow").className = "downarrowimage";

 } else {

 document.getElementById("level1").className = "level1drop";

 }

}
```

Works beautifully and is cross-browser. A little crude, but oh well.